# AssertWasCalled() equivalent where method not known at compile-time

Tags: c#, reflection, rhino-mocks

I have a Rhino-mocked object and I have a MethodInfo representing a method on the interface being mocked. I want to tell whether the method represented by the MethodInfo has been called on the mock object.

If I knew the method at compile-time, I'd use the Rhino AssertWasCalled() method.

If I had a day or two spare, I might work out the Expression Tree magic to generate the code, but that's more than this problem's currently worth.

I am wondering whether I have missed an easier way. Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You assume the use of expression-trees here would complicate things too much, but I disagree:

```
// What you have:
var methodInfo = typeof(ICloneable).GetMethod("Clone");

var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ICloneable), "p");
var body = Expression.Call(parameter, methodInfo);

// Rhino can accept this as an expectation.
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<ICloneable>>(body, parameter).Compile();
```

And then use it like:

```
var clone = new MockRepository().Stub<ICloneable>();
clone.Replay();
clone.Clone();
clone.AssertWasCalled(lambda);
```

Comment: Thanks. This has encouraged me to have another go, but my situation is not as simple. My method has a parameter.

Comment: So what sort of argument validation are you going to be doing? `Arg<Blah>.Is.Anything`? You can create that with reflection, you know.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following, based on the helpful comments of Ani above.

This is test code, so I am sanguine about the `GetParameters()[0]` horror!

```
    protected static object InvokeOldOperation<TCurrentInterface>(MethodInfo oldOperationMethod, object implToTest, TCurrentInterface mockCurrentImpl)
    {
        MethodInfo currentInterfaceMethod = typeof(TCurrentInterface).GetMethod(oldOperationMethod.Name);

        Type oldRequestType = oldOperationMethod.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;
        var request = Activator.CreateInstance(oldRequestType);

        Type currentRequestType = currentInterfaceMethod.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType;

        ParameterExpression instanceParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TCurrentInterface), "i");
        var requestParameter = Expression.Constant(null, currentRequestType);
        MethodCallExpression body = Expression.Call(instanceParameter, currentInterfaceMethod, new Expression[] { requestParameter});
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TCurrentInterface, object>>(body, instanceParameter).Compile();

        var response = oldOperationMethod.Invoke(implToTest, new[] {request});
        mockCurrentImpl.AssertWasCalled(lambda, opt => opt.Constraints(Is.TypeOf(currentRequestType)).Repeat.Once());

        return response;
    }
```